# How to manage link in the react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating simple route and link. I am using `react-router-dom` v6. When I am clicking the button I am going from `http://localhost:3000/home` to `http://localhost:3000/home/trend`. But I need to go to `http://localhost:3000/trend`. How to do that?

Home index.jsx

```
<li>
  <Link to="/home">
    <HomeIcon />
    Home
  </Link>
</li>
<li>
  <Link to="trend">
    <WhatshotIcon />
    Trending
  </Link>
</li>
```

App.jsx

```
const App = () =>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/trend" element={<Trend />} />
      <Route
        path="/auth"
        element={localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
          ? <Navigate to="/" />
          : <Auth/>
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="/register"
        element={localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
          ? <Navigate to="/" />
          : <Regis/>
        }
      />
      <Route path="/setting" element={<Setting />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
;

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the path relative to the `root URL`, just add a slash `/` before the path.

```
<Link to="/trend">
  <WhatshotIcon />
  Trending
</Link>
```

Because without slash it will be relative to the current path.